# Monitor google sheet change event externally

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, next.js

What I'm doing - I am reading data from a google sheet using a NodeJS/NextJS app
What I need - I want to update data in my app when sheet's data changes

Is there a way to trigger something like an http request from google sheet when a data change happen? Is there any other way in which I can gain real time changes on google sheet?

Comment: About `a data change`, In your situation, how are the cells of the Spreadsheet edited? The cell is manually edited by a user? The cell is edited by Google Apps Script? Or, The cell is edited by Node.js?

Comment: @Tanaike Manually edited by a user using the UI

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about using OnEdit trigger? I thought that [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) can be used.